# MFC Thread-safe singleton

Tags: multithreading, mfc, singleton

I want to create a thread-safe singleton **using only MFC**. I prefer to avoid boost::thread, and I can't use std::thread on VS2010.
Also, VS 2010 has C++11 limitations (if not, it would be much easier since I think it supports thread-safe static variable initialization).

So far, I have tried this solution but I'm not sure how thread-safe it is.
From my understanding, a problem would be that the static CCriticalSection was initialized after the singleton instance is created and some trouble would appear if two threads get an instance and generate two singleton objects.

In my case there will be only two threads running simultaneously, one main thread and one worker thread. The main thread will get the first instance, and the worker threads will get instances from time to time afterwards.

In this scenario, is this class thread-safe enough? Am I missing something?
In case that there's no way to do a thread-safe enough singleton class with MFC only I'll consider boost. Any advice or suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
// Singleton.h

class CSingleton
{    
    static CCriticalSection m_cs;
    public:
    static CSingleton& GetInstance()
    {   
        m_cs.Lock();        
        static CSingleton instance;
        m_cs.Unlock();      
        return instance;
    }   
    virtual ~CSingleton(){};

    private:
    CSingleton(){};                     // Constructor  
    CSingleton( CSingleton const& );    // Don't Implement
    void operator=( CSingleton const& ); 
}   

// Singleton.cpp

// Initialize Critical Section
CCriticalSection CSingleton::m_cs;
```